# requestBody not displaying subtypes with arrays within a $ref component but shows correctly in response body

Tags: swagger, openapi

I've been struggling with an issue in an openapi 3.0.1 spec json document I've been working on.

The issue I'm seeing in the online swagger editor (editor.swagger.io) is very strange where the Request body Example Value section of a POST does not show the "layers", which is an array defined within my MixBase schema component, based on the MixLayer schema component.  The MixLayer schema component has an array of MixLayerComponent schema components.
However, if I include a $ref to the MixBase schema in the responses section, all the elements are shown correctly.

Request body Example Value section that is missing the 'layers':

```
{
  "mixId": "4f8b533f-7449-4056-92ff-11b1de94d656",
  "mixDescription": "SES5M",
  "mixScaleName": "MyScale",
  "mixRoom": "MixingRoomABC",
  "mixProgramId": "ABC-123-ProgramId",
  "mixDateTime": "2018-06-07T12:51:25.077Z",
  "mixState": "Paused",
  "mixNumber": "131",
  "mixedByUserName": "john.smith@example.com",
  "mixedByFirstName": "John",
  "mixedByLastName": "Smith"
}
```

Responses Example Value section returning the correct list of elements including 'layers':

```
{
  "mixId": "4f8b533f-7449-4056-92ff-11b1de94d656",
  "mixDescription": "SES5M",
  "mixScaleName": "MyScale",
  "mixRoom": "MixingRoomABC",
  "mixProgramId": "ABC-123-ProgramId",
  "mixDateTime": "2018-06-07T12:51:25.077Z",
  "mixState": "Paused",
  "mixNumber": "131",
  "mixedByUserName": "john.smith@example.com",
  "mixedByFirstName": "John",
  "mixedByLastName": "Smith",
  "layers": [                   -- this represents the MixLayer component
     {
      "unitOfMeasure": "g",
      "Components": [           -- this represents the MixLayerComponent correctly
        {
          "code": "800C",
          "description": "800C",
          "poured": 204.5,
          "density": 1.041
        }
    ]
 }
```

]
}

My requestBody section is defined as: (doesn't show 'layers')

```
 requestBody:
    required: true
    description: Paint mix information to create
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/MixBase'
```

My responses section is defined as: (and this displays correctly in the Response examples section)

```
responses:
    '200':
      description: Success
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/MixBase'
```

Here is the definition of the 'layers' within the MixBase schema component (which is the last element in the MixBase definition which is why additionalProperties is set to false): (The formatting might not be correct in stack overflow but the swagger editor doesn't complain so I don't believe the issue is linked to formatting)

```
layers:
      description: Layer related information for components of the mix
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/MixLayer'
      readOnly: true
  additionalProperties: false
```

Here is the definition of the MixLayer:

```
MixLayer:
  required:
    - Components
  type: object
  properties:
    unitOfMeasure:
      description: Unit of volume for the components of the layer
      maxLength: 10
      type: string
      nullable: true
      example: g
    Components:
      description: The components that make up the layer in the mix
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/MixLayerComponent'
      readOnly: true
  additionalProperties: false
```

Here is the definition of the MixLayerComponent:

```
MixLayerComponent:
  required:
    - code
    - density
    - poured
  type: object
  properties:
    code:
      description: The code associated with the mix component of the layer
      maxLength: 25
      minLength: 1
      type: string
      example: 800C
    description:
      description: The description of the mix component of the layer
      maxLength: 120
      type: string
      nullable: true
      example: 800C
    poured:
      description: >-
        The quantity, expressed in the unit of measurement, consumed for the
        mix component
      type: number
      format: double
      example: 204.5
    density:
      description: The density associated with the mix component of the layer
      type: number
      format: double
      example: 1.041
  additionalProperties: false
```

I thought that the "Components" element in the MixLayer component schema might be a reserved keyword in openapi so I changed the references to something else and it still has the same issue.

I thought this issue might be with the online swagger editor (editor.swagger.io) but the same thing occurs in Postman.  I also tried browsers Chrome, Edge, and Firefox and they all
have the same issue.  I have also tried an XML content type in addition to the JSON I would like to use but still the same issue.

I don't access to post my openapi.json file on stack overflow but I hope this provides enough information.

Any insights anyone has for me to continue a line of investigation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

`layers` is defined as a read-only property (`readOnly: true`) - that's why it doesn't appear in the request body example.

Comment: Thank you so much Helen!  I was hoping it was something easy that I overlooked.  You're a lifesaver! :)